# ¿Como ordenar un array de numeros aletorios?

Tags: array, c, bucles, menu

**Ya realicé el 1er y el 3er punto ya que van de la mano** Pero no logro realizar el segundo punto donde tengo que ordenar el arreglo aleatorio ya realizado en el primer punto. Por ende el 4to punto tampoco lo pude resolver porque va ligado con el 2do.

Realice un programa que realice las funciones que a continuación se indican. Todas las opciones deben ser
presentadas al usuario a través de un menú de opciones.

• Escriba una función en la que se generen de manera aleatoria 100 números enteros y guardarlos en un arreglo

• Escriba una función que ordene los numeros que se generaron en la opción 1 y guardelos en otro arreglo

• Escriba una función que busque un número en el arreglo que se generaron los números aleatorios, de forma secuencial

• Escriba una función que realice una busqueda binaria en el arreglo ordenado

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<windows.h>

int  crear(), volver() ,buscar(), ordenar() , binaria() ;
int opc, a[100] ,m,v, i ,j,aux; // variables globales

int main()
{// inicio main




    do{ 
    system("cls");
    printf("\t ***MENU DE OPCIONIES***\n \n");
    printf(" \n 1.- Crear 100 numeros aleatorios y guardarlos");
    printf("\n 2.- Ordenar los numeros aleatorios previamente guardados");
    printf("\n 3.- Buscar un numero en el arreglo aleatorio ");
    printf("\n 4.- Realizar una busqueda binaria en el arreglo ordenado");
    printf("\n 5.- Salir");
    printf("\n Opcion a escoger: ");
    scanf("%i", &opc);
    system("cls");
    switch(opc)
    { // inicio de switch
        system("cls");
        case 1: crear();
            break;
        
        
        
        case 2: ordenar();
            break;
            
            
        case 3: buscar();
            break;
            
            
        case 4: binaria();
            break;
} // fin de switch      
}while(opc!=5);
return 0;
} //fin main

/////-----Crear de manera aleatoria 100 números enteros y guardarlos en un arreglo---- -/////
int crear()
{
system("cls");
srand(time(0));
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    a[i] = rand()% (100)+1;
}  

for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    printf("  %d \n" , a[i]);
}
volver();
}
/////-----Ordenar los numeros aleatorios previamente guardados-----/////
int ordenar()
{//inicio ordenar

system("cls");

for(i=100;i>=0;i--){
    for(j=100;j>=0;j--){
        if(a[j] > a[j-1]){
            aux = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = aux;
        }
    }
}
printf("\nLos numeros ordenados descendentemente son: \n");
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    printf(" %d \n", a[j]);
}
volver();
} //fin ordenar



/////-----Buscar un numero en el arreglo aleatorio-----/////

int buscar(){
int a[i];
int bandera=0;
int busqueda;
int x;

printf("\n Digite el numero que busca: ");
scanf("%i", &busqueda);
for(x=0;x<=100;x++){
if(a[x]==busqueda) 
bandera=1;
}   
if(bandera==1){
printf("Dato %i encontrado", busqueda);
} else{
printf("Dato No encontrado");
}

volver();

}
/////-----función que realice una busqueda binaria en el arreglo ordenado-----/////










/////-----Volver-----/////
int volver(){ //inicio volver

printf("\n ***Presionar (1) para volver al menu principal***");
scanf("%i",&v);
if(v==1){
    system("cls");
    main();
}
} //fin volver
```

Comment: Posiblemente alguien ya haya hecho una pregunta similar. Mira el sitio por si a caso.

Comment: Que tal, Ricardo. Si buscas en el sitio palabras clave como, "guardar elementos en un array en c", quizás encuentres la respuesta a lo que estás buscando

Comment: Por ejemplo, esta:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/559885/crear-un-array-con-las-posiciones-de-los-elementos-ordenados-de-otro-array