# Crear un array con las posiciones de los elementos ordenados de otro array

Tags: c

> Se solicita crear un vector P que contenga la posición de los elementos de A, para que la lista se recorra ordenada de menor a mayor. Lista A de M naturales.

Al generar el vector P me muestra números que no son los que deseo. No sé si me estaría mostrando la dirección de memoria.

Primero intenté hacerlo con el ciclo *for* pero lo cambié pensando que eso era lo que estaba mal. Tambien intenté usar pos como puntero pero no puedo solucionarlo.

```
typedef int T_vector[101];

void cargar_vector(T_vector, short *);
void generar_p(T_vector, short, T_vector);
void mostrar_vector(T_vector, short);
int main()
{
    T_vector A, P;
    short M;
    cargar_vector(A, &M);
    
    generar_p(A, M, P);
    
    mostrar_vector(A, M);
    
    mostrar_vector(P, M);
    
    return 0;
}
void cargar_vector(T_vector A, short *M)
{
    int i;
    printf("Ingrese el tamaño del vector: ");
    scanf("%hd", M);
    for (i = 1; i <= *M; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese el elemento %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
}
void generar_p(T_vector A, short M, T_vector P)
{ /*fijar con recorrer vector*/
    int men, i, j, l, k;
    short pos;
    men = A[1];
    j = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= M; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] < men)
        {
            men = A[i];
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    P[j] = pos;
    j++;
    l = 1;
    k = M;
    for (i = 1; i <= M; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] >= men && i != pos)
        {
            while (A[i] < A[l] && A[i] < A[k])
            {
                P[j] = i;
                j++;
                l++;
                k--;
            } 
        }
    }
}
void mostrar_vector(T_vector P, short M)
{
    int j;
    printf("El vector es :");
    for (j = 1; j <= M; j++)
    {
        printf("%d|", P[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por posición entiendo que debe ser relativo. Por ejemplo el primer elemento sería 0, el segundo 1 y así. Si vas a usar punteros, debes tener en cuenta que para un número en una variable `int`, lo mejor sería usar un puntero `int*` porque `short` es de menor tamaño y al leer el número en la misma posición de memoria con `short*` estarías perdiendo información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a empezar por `cargar_vector`:

- No hay ninguna necesidad de que reciba `M`. Eso debería ser un parámetro de salida
- Los índices empiezan en 0, no en 1. Estás desperdiciando la primera posición de `A`
- O pasas a usar memoria dinámica o verificas que el tamaño del vector no supere las 101 posiciones

Aplicando los cambios:

```
short cargar_vector(T_vector A)
{
    short num_elementos;
    do {
        printf("Ingrese el tamaño del vector: ");
        scanf("%hd", &num_elementos);
    } while (num_elementos > 101);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_elementos; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese el elemento %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    return num_elementos;
}
```

Vamos con `generar_p`.

Sería más sencillo si inicialiases `P` con una secuencia incremental. Así, el elemento `P[n]` apuntaría al elemento `A[n]`.

Una vez hecho esto puedes programar facilmente el algoritmo de la burbuja para que vaya moviendo los índices de `P` según la ordenación que te están pidiendo:

```
void generar_p(T_vector A, short M, T_vector P)
{
    // Inicializamos  P
    for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        P[i] = i;
    }

    // Ordenamos P
    for (int i=0; i<M-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<M; j++)
        {
            if (A[P[i]] > A[P[j]])
            {
                int temp = P[i];
                P[i] = P[j];
                P[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si ahora quieres mostrar el vector `A` ordenado según la secuencia dada por `P`, necesitas una función nueva:

```
void mostrar_vector_ordenado(T_vector datos, T_vector orden, short num_elementos)
{
    printf("El vector ordenado es: ");
    for (int i=0; i<num_elementos; i++)
    {
        printf("%d|", datos[orden[i]]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder.
La forma de cargar_vector y lo de los indices empezarlos en 1 es una regla por así decirlo de la materia que estoy cursando, soy consciente de que empiezan en 0, gracias por esa aclaración.
Me quedó una duda, porque el vector no debe tener un tamaño mayor a 10?

Comment: @LucasAgustínCastroMontaño no quería decir 10 sino 101, el tamaño del array. Al copiar el tamaño del array me faltó el último dígito, ahora lo corrijo. Por otro lado, quien te enseñe con esa norma no tiene ni idea de programar, así te sugiero olvidarte de ese mal vicio en cuanto tengas ocasión

Comment: Si tienes que empezar con el índice 1, entonces el tamaño máximo será, obviamente, de 100

Answer (score 0):

Respondo a esta pregunta sólo para desempolvar mi C, y para eso tomé la respuesta aceptada de @eferion y:

1. La refactoricé modularizándola y aplicando el Single Responsibility Principle
2. Use un struct donde cada atributo tiene o los valores, el orden, y el tamaño
3. Utilicé punteros

Primero creé dos archivos al nivel del principal. Uno llamado *t_vector.c* (con todas las funciones de adquisición y ordenamiento), y otro *t_vector.h* (con los tipos de datos de cada función de *t_vector.c*).

*t_vector.h*:

```c
#ifndef _LIBRARY
#define _LIBRARY

typedef struct T_vector {
    int* values; // Sería el contenido de "A" en tu tarea
    int* order; // Tambien llamado "B" en tu tarea
    int size;
} T_vector;

T_vector initialize_t_vector(int size);
void initialize_t_vector_order_incremental(T_vector t_vector);
void swap(int* order, int first, int second);
void set_t_vector_order(T_vector t_vector);
int* generate_t_vector_values(int size);
void print_t_vector_ordered_values(T_vector t_vector);
T_vector t_vector_factory(int* values, int size);

#include "t_vector.c"

#endif
```

*t_vector.c*:

```c
#include "t_vector.h"

T_vector initialize_t_vector(int size) {
    T_vector t_vector;
    t_vector.values = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    t_vector.order = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    t_vector.size = size;
    return t_vector;
}

void initialize_t_vector_order_incremental(T_vector t_vector) {
    int* order = t_vector.order;
    for(int i = 0; i < t_vector.size; i++)
        order[i] = i;
}

void swap(int* order, int first, int second) {
    int temp = order[first];
    order[first] = order[second];
    order[second] = temp;
}

void set_t_vector_order(T_vector t_vector) {
    int* values = t_vector.values;
    int* order = t_vector.order;
    int size = t_vector.size;

    initialize_t_vector_order_incremental(t_vector);

    for (int i=0; i < size-1; i++)
        for (int j=i+1; j< size; j++)
            if (values[order[i]] > values[order[j]])
                swap(order, i, j);
}

int* generate_t_vector_values(int size) {
    int* values = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Ingrese el elemento %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &values[i]);
    }
    return values;
}

void print_t_vector_ordered_values(T_vector t_vector) {
    int* values = t_vector.values;
    int* order = t_vector.order;
    for (int i = 0; i < t_vector.size; i++)
        printf("%d|", values[order[i]]);
    printf("\n");
}

T_vector t_vector_factory(int* values, int size) {
    T_vector t_vector = initialize_t_vector(size);
    t_vector.values = values;
    set_t_vector_order(t_vector);
    return t_vector;
}
```

Después los mandé a llamar en la función principal *vector.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "t_vector.h"

int ask_size() {
    int size;
    printf("Ingresa el tamano del vector: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    return size;
}

int main() {

    int size = ask_size();
    int* vector_values = generate_t_vector_values(size);
    T_vector A = t_vector_factory(vector_values, size);

    print_t_vector_ordered_values(A);

    return 0;
}
```

Ya con esto la función principal queda "limpia" y clara.

Al correr nos da:

```bash
$ gcc vector.c -o vector && ./vector
Ingresa el tamano del vector: 3
Ingrese el elemento 1: 123
Ingrese el elemento 2: 4
Ingrese el elemento 3: 323
4|123|323|
```

Tan sólo lo hice para reaprender mi C, y para compartir mi "reaprendizaje".